# Perl : map statement

Tags: perl, dictionary

I would like your help, because I am not able to understand what the following line means:

```
map {@$_[1 .. 4]} @msft
```

found in the example code of [GD::Graph::ohlc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GD%3a%3aGraph%3a%3aohlc).
Could you please provide me with a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@msft` is an array of arrays where each inner array contains 5 items (date, open/low/high/close prices).

The `map` takes each element of `@msft`, which is an array reference stored in `$_` and dereferences it via `@$_` and takes a slice of that array (namely the second through fifth items since the array is 0-based) via the `[1..4]`.  It then returns those four items.  `map` concatenates them into a single list.

In essence, it is flattening the array of arrays of five elements into a single array made up of the 2nd through 5th items of each subarray.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of `@msft` are array references. The code collects elements 1 through 4 from each array into a single list:

```
my @msft = (
    [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    [0,11,22,33,44,55],
    [0,111,222,333,444,555],
);

my @result = map {@$_[1 .. 4]} @msft;

print "@result\n";  # 1 2 3 4 11 22 33 44 111 222 333 444
```

From the [documentation for map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each
>   element of LIST (locally setting $_ to
>   each element) and returns the list
>   value composed of the results of each
>   such evaluation.